# Why my code is giving compile time error?

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I'm trying to get this question but unable to understand why is it giving compile - time error
My code is :

```
#include<stdio.h>
static struct student
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;
}s1={6,7,8,9},s2={4,3,2,1},s3;
void main()
{
    s3=s1+s2;
    clrscr();
    printf("%d %d %d %d",s3.a,s3.b,s3.c,s3.d);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Where have you declared `s1`, `s2` and `s3`? What are those?

Comment: what about name the error? Same as asking "What Am I doing wrong?", without telling us what you do ;)

Comment: Please add the Error Message and fix the indentation of your code.

Comment: Read the error messages!

Answer (score 5):

You cannot do this `s3=s1+s2;` - this can be done only if the `+` operator is overloaded for your struct. And operator overloading is not supported in C. This is what you need:

```
s3.a=s1.a+s2.a;
s3.b=s1.b+s2.b;
....
```

[How structs work.](http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx1c.html)

Answer (score 5):

You will have to manually add each member.

```
s3.a = s1.a + s2.a;
```

And so on...

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read the [About](http://stackoverflow.com/about) page soon. For now, please read [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 2):

You can't add structures like this

```
s3=s1+s2;
```

### [Operations on Structures](http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx1c.html):

> There is a relatively small number of operations which `C` directly supports on structures. As we've seen, we can define structures, declare variables of structure type, and select the members of structures. We can also assign entire structures: the expression
>
> ```
> c1 = c2
> ```
>
> would assign all of `c2` to `c1` (both the real and imaginary parts, assuming the preceding declarations). We can also pass structures as arguments to functions, and declare and define functions which return structures. **But to do anything else, we typically have to write our own code** (often as functions). For example, we could write a function to add two complex numbers:

```
struct complex
cpx_add(struct complex c1, struct complex c2)
{
    struct complex sum;
    sum.real = c1.real + c2.real;
    sum.imag = c1.imag + c2.imag;
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

define an addition operator or use `s3.a = s1.a + s2.a; s3.b = s1.b + s2.b; etc`

Answer (score 1):

**Problem :** Adding `structures` as `s3=s1+s2;` is not possible.
if you want to add the values from structure 1 `s1` and structure 2 `s2`

Try This:

```
s3.a=s1.a+s2.a;
s3.b=s1.b+s2.b;
s3.c=s1.c+s2.c;
s3.d=s1.c+s2.c;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't add a structure to another here: `s3=s1+s2;`
If you need this functional i would recommend to create a function to do it, for example

```
struct student add_up_students(struct student *s1, struct student *s2) {
    struct student s = {0};
    s.a= s1->a + s2->a;
    s.b= s1->b + s2->b;
    s.c= s1->c + s2->c;
    s.d= s1->d + s2->d;
    return s;
}
```

And use it:

```
s3 = add_up_students(&s1, &s2);
```

That prints what you expected.